# select row and max value from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                     FROM farm_flocks 
                     WHERE Client_Id='" .$_SESSION["id"] . "' 
                     THEN 
                     SELECT Flock_id in (
                           select max(Flock_id) from 
                           farm_flocks
                     )", $connection);

        if (mysql_num_rows($query) == 1) {

            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

            //do some stuff

        }
```

Trying to select all the rows that have the same client Id then after that narrow it the selection down to 1 row by selecting the highest value from the Flock_id column.

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used.

Comment: Your query is so far from making sense, that the question is not clear.  Provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 3):

Change your query as follows.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT *, max(Flock_id) AS Max_Flock_id FROM farm_flocks WHERE Client_Id='" .$_SESSION["id"] . "')", $connection);
```

Also, `mysql_*` is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used.

Comment: Keep getting this error now though, however when I excute in php admin it seems to work fine. Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean

Comment: check the error using `mysql_error()` make some efforts also check your mysql connection.